# Generate managed wrapper for Media Foundation

Tags: .net, managed, ms-media-foundation

MF team has provided MFManagedEncode which is written in C#, inside the source they have created wrapper for a lot of MF interfaces but not all interfaces, is there have any tool can generate the wrapper for rest interfaces automatically? if no, i need write the wrapper by myself, but where can i find the GUID of COM and the IID of the interface? MSDN just mentioned the interface belong which lib, for example, what's the IID of IMFMediaStream interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snarfle has created a managed wrapper for MF

http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/

Grab the source from svn, if you need the new interfaces added in Windows 7